# XPath to return only specific child nodes but with the parent - possible?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

Say I have XML like this:

```
<Entity>
    <Record name="My Record 1" id="3a41b5c1-2462-e211-8a1c-005056b02dd2" count="1">
        <Data name="ec_name" value="My Name 1" linked="false" />
        <Data name="ec_allteams" value="100000000" linked="false" />
        <Data name="ec_teamtype" value="100000001" linked="false" />
    </Record>
    <Record name="My Record 2" id="3a41b5c1-2462-e211-8a1c-005056b02dd3" count="2">
        <Data name="ec_name" value="My Name 2" linked="false" />
        <Data name="ec_allteams" value="100000002" linked="false" />
        <Data name="ec_teamtype" value="100000003" linked="true" />
    </Record>
    <Record name="My Record 3" id="3a41b5c1-2462-e211-8a1c-005056b02dd4" count="3">
        <Data name="ec_name" value="My Name 3" linked="false" />
        <Data name="ec_allteams" value="100000004" linked="false" />
        <Data name="ec_teamtype" value="100000005" linked="false" />
    </Record>
</Entity>
```

What would be the XPath to only return Record + Data child nodes where linked='true'? For example, I want to get the following result:

```
    <Record name="My Record 2" id="3a41b5c1-2462-e211-8a1c-005056b02dd3" count="2">
        <Data name="ec_teamtype" value="100000003" linked="true" />
    </Record>
```

Is this possible in XPath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to get exactly that, but you could get the Data node, and then read it's parent:

Data node: `/Entity/Record/Data[@linked='true']`

Record node containing the child with linked=true: `/Entity/Record[Data/@linked='true']`

Comment: I thought so :( Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

to get all Data nodes where linked = true

```
//Data[@linked='true']
```

to get the parent where linked = true

```
//Data[@linked='true']/..
```

this will return both the parent and the child node that has linked=true

```
//Data[@linked='true']//parent
```